# Android dynamic title bar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have one activity with 3 fragments, (top, center, bottom), and the top fragment it's like a title bar that I want to display different names and buttons, corresponding to the current screen. How can I implement this ?

Thanks, 
Pedro Simão

Answer (score 1):

The top bar that you are referring to as title bar is called an action bar in Android. You can do the following to change the text on this action bar as follows.

```
// Inside your activity
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setTitle("My title");
```

You can then implement change the title according to whatever logic you'd like.

Comment: I set my activity to " android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" >" cuz I dont want to use android action bar, I'm making a custom action bar designed by myself. Can I do the same ?

Comment: It should be possible but I'm not sure how you will implement the setTitle() api in yours.